# Looking for neighbors in a matrix and store it

Tags: javascript, neighbours

I'm trying with Javascript to check if a position of an array has a neighbor and then, store it, but I'm getting an error that I don't understand why happens.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined
    at BeginGame (script.js:250)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):41)
```

There's the code:

```
        for(var i=0;i<gridWidth;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<gridHeight;j++){

                if(PuzzleMatrix[i-1][j-1]!=null){
                    vecinos.push(PuzzleMatrix[i-1][j-1]);

                }else if(PuzzleMatrix[i][j-1]!=null){
                    vecinos.push(PuzzleMatrix[i][j-1]);

                }else if(PuzzleMatrix[i+1][j-1]!=null){
                    vecinos.push(PuzzleMatrix[i+1][j-1]);

                }else if(PuzzleMatrix[i-1][j]!=null){
                    vecinos.push(PuzzleMatrix[i-1][j]);

                }else if(PuzzleMatrix[i+1][j]!=null){
                    vecinos.push(PuzzleMatrix[i+1][j]);

                }else if(PuzzleMatrix[i-1][j+1]!=null){
                    vecinos.push(PuzzleMatrix[i-1][j+1]);

                }else if(PuzzleMatrix[i][j+1]!=null){
                    vecinos.push(PuzzleMatrix[i][j+1]);

                }else if(PuzzleMatrix[i+1][j+1]!=null){
                    vecinos.push(PuzzleMatrix[i+1][j+1]);
                }
          }
      }
```

Comment: First time it runs both i and j are 0 so this -> `PuzzleMatrix[i-1][j-1]` is equivalent to `PuzzleMatrix[-1][-1]`, which will never work.  `PuzzleMatrix[-1]` returns undefined and you then try to get `undefined[-1]`

Comment: But, this is the reason why I'm trying to check if this position is != null, and I'm still getting the error..

Comment: Yes, because you're checking `if (undefined[-1] != null)`.  That's exactly what I've explained in my comment.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Start the loops at 1 instead of 0. Was hoping you'd figure that out when I explained the problem.